# SQL data retrieval based on dates and keys

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with the following data:

```
Emp no   Emp name   Emp Status  Emp reference   EmpCanc reference      date and time

1        Jhon       Active       20               20C               20120110 12:20:08
2        steve      inactive     21               20                20120110 12:25:08
```

From the above data I would like to retrieve records based on the `Emp reference` and `EmpCanc reference` values. Date and time should also be between `20120110 15:30:01` and `20120110 15:00:00`.

I need the output below because `Emp reference` of first record and `EmpCanc reference` of second record are equal.

```
Emp NO Emp name  Emp Status   

1      Jhon      Active
2      steve     inactive
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select empreference, EmpCanc 
  from Tablename 
 where dateandtime > to_date('01/10/2012 15:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
   and dateandtime < to_date('01/10/2012 15:30:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
```

Comment: Date condition is fine,How can i check the data

Comment: b:  I dont know the values initially ,So i have to check the condition dynamically like emp reference=empcanc reference.

Comment: select empreference, EmpCanc from Tablename where dataandtime > TO_DATE('01/10/2012 15:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and dataandtime < TO_DATE('01/10/2012 15:30:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and empreference = EmpCanc

Comment: select empreference, EmpCanc from Tablename where dataandtime > TO_DATE('01/10/2012 15:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and dataandtime < TO_DATE('01/10/2012 15:30:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS') and empreference = EmpCanc

Comment: I want between date and time.

Comment: not working,giving error :Correct the format string to match the literal

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you can do a self-join, but that will not list the second "inactive" row as follows:

```
SELECT Tablename."Emp no", Tablename."Emp Name", Tablename."Emp Status"
FROM Tablename INNER JOIN Tablename AS Tablename_1 ON Tablename."Emp reference" = Tablename_1."Emp Canc reference"
WHERE (((Tablename."date and time") Between TO_DATE('01/10/2012 15:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')  And TO_DATE('01/10/2012 15:30:01', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')))
```

Comment: Hi,Getting error: Correct the format string to match the literal

Comment: Sorry, but since I don't know exactly what your field names are, this is really just a sample that I did not expect to work. You may try commenting out the Between state - I just copied the TO_DATE from a previous contributor. HTH

Comment: I think you need to supply a larger data sample. It is also not clear whether you want to select all rows with matching "emp" and "empCanc" or just alternating rows? Or what?

Comment: please give me sample for above data if date and time is greaterthan and lessthan or equals 15:30:01 and 15:00:00